# Is it safe to share a file handle between two processes in PHP?

Tags: php, fork

I've found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2358684/759866) here on Stack but I'm not sure whether they apply to PHP.

I'd like to create child processes with [pcntl_fork()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php). I want to write messages to a log file, from both the parent and the child processes.

If I open a file handle in the parent, is it safe to write to the same handle from the childs? Note that I will only be appending to the file.

I'm afraid of the race conditions that could happen, in particular if the two processes are executed on different cores: what would happen if two processes executing on two different cores were to write to the same file handle at the same time?

Comment: have you considered `Thread` and `Mutex`

Comment: @Baba No I haven't, actually I wasn't aware of these classes, however I'm not comfortable using them in a production environment, as the `pthreads` extension is beta (current version 0.0.44), and not readily available as an RPM package. Anyway, does that mean that it's not safe to do it without some kind of mutex?

Comment: Try 'n Error!
Use flock or: dont use a file descriptor, use a stream to syslog or similiar. Stresstesting this might not be difficult, what you think.
or use databases. files and I/O are oldschool

Comment: @Benjamin it can be safely shared ... and using pthreads  in production and its working perfectly fine ...  Even with `flock` you can encore only once process is accessing the file as demonstrated : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16998949/1226894

Comment: Actually I just realized that `flock()` operated on a resource, and not on a file name! Which makes it perfect to allow two processes to share the same handle (each if them can lock the resource when they need to write to it). Just out of interest, what would happen if we didn't use `flock()`? Would `fwrite()` calls from different processes be serialized anyway, even if they're happening at the same time, or could some weird error happen?

Comment: @Baba You can add your comment as an answer, by the way, your answer on the other question explains it pretty well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flock` or `streamWrapper::stream_lock` as the case may be or `stream_set_blocking`

> [flock()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) allows you to perform a simple reader/writer model which can be used on virtually every platform (including most Unix derivatives and even Windows).

`flock` works on file resource and is closed automatically if `fclose()` even if the file is not unlocked.

```
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
```

You can loop and wait until the file is ready to be opened for writing in my case am using `c+`

```
while(! $fp = @fopen($this->file, "c+")) {
    if (time() - $time > $this->timeout)
        throw new Exception("File can not be accessed");
    usleep(100000);
}
```

`$this->timeout` is basically how long you ended to wait for the file a good example can be found [PHP issues using flock - file locking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16998949/1226894)

Comment: Thanks, does `c+` make `flock()` unnecessary?

Comment: Not useless you still need `flock` but the file is not appended not truncated like `w` ... would updated my answer to certify tha